# SQL Server: Updating a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a TblA

```
ID Match Code Status
1   001   A    
2   001   B   
3   002   A
4   003   A
5   003   V
6   004   A
7   004   B
```

I want to populate Status with 'FAIL' according to :
Code "A" and "B" should both exist for every match number. For 001,002,003 both A, B should exist. if not, FAIL the whole Match. Expected table:

```
ID Match Code Status
1   001   A    NULL
2   001   B    NULL
3   002   A    FAIL
4   003   A    FAIL
5   003   V    FAIL
6   004   A    NULL
7   004   B    NULL
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
update [TblA]
set [Status] = 'FAIL' where 
Match NOT in
(select match from tblA where Code = 'A'
intersect
select match from tblA where Code = 'B');
```

Comment: If there are only a small number of additional codes like v it is acceptable to add additional intersects in the subquery one after the other.

Comment: I may have edited over someone's comment...apologies for that...still an overflow noob.

Comment: +1 nice and simple. I would have somehow aggregated the whole thing and made it more complex than it needed to be.

Comment: Thanks Lieven, An aggregated subquery was the first thing to pop into my head as well.